# Bifurcation Diagram of Chua Circuit

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am currently working on a Bifurcation Diagram for Chua's Circuit but I am having trouble coming up with code for a bifurcation of a system of equations.

The following equations are given in the first page of the document
http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~chua/papers/Aguirre97.pdf

I would like to analyze the changes in the resistance variable R.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Here is my code so far

```
g[v1_] := Piecewise[{{m0*v1 + (m0 - m1)*E1, 
 v1 <= -E1}, {m1*v1, -E1 < v1 < E1}, {m0*v1 + (m1 - m0)*E1, 
 v1 >= E1}}];

Plot[g[v1], {v1, -E1 - 10, E1 + 10}]

system = {i'[t] == -v2[t]/L + i[t]*rL, 
   v2'[t] == i[t]/C2 + 1/(Rt*C2)*(v1[t] - v2[t]), 
   v1'[t] == 1/C1*(((1/Rt)*(v2[t] - v1[t])) - g[v1])};

sol = ParametricNDSolve[system, {i, v2, v1}, {t, 0, 100}, {Rt, rL}]
```

I am getting errors when trying to solve this. Mathematica tells me that v1 appears with no arguments, I assume this is from the piecewise function g[v1]. Essentially I would like to solve this and vary one of the parameters (rL or Rt) and use that to make a bifurcation diagram of the system (or at least a parametric plot). Please help!

Comment: It is very unlikely that someone would be willing to read an entire paper and code up equations for it to help you analyze changes in some variable. Instead, here's what you should do to improve your chances: 1) Include the relevant equations in the question to limit the scope (this site supports latex via mathjax) 2) Explain what you want to use those equations for, and if there's a derived form that you're interested in, include that as well. 3) Include your attempts at coding up the equations. People are much more likely to help if you show what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: This may be helpful for coding: http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/~mcc/Chaos_Course/Chua/Chua_eq.pdf

Comment: `m0 = 1; m1 = 0.5; E1 = 2; ClearAll[i, t, v1, v2, rL, Rt]; R1 = 1; C2 \
= 1; L = 1; C1 = 1;g[v1_] := 
  Piecewise[{{m0*v1 + (m0 - m1)*E1, 
     v1 <= -E1}, {m1*v1, -E1 < v1 < E1}, {m0*v1 + (m1 - m0)*E1, 
     v1 >= E1}}];

Plot[g[v1], {v1, -E1 - 10, E1 + 10}]

system = {i'[t] == -v2[t]/L + i[t]*rL, 
   v2'[t] == i[t]/C2 + 1/(Rt*C2)*(v1[t] - v2[t]), 
   v1'[t] == 1/C1*(((1/Rt)*(v2[t] - v1[t])) - g[v1[t]]), v1[0] == 0, 
   v2[0] == 0, i[0] == 0.1};

sol = ParametricNDSolve[system, {i, v2, v1}, {t, 0, 100}, {Rt, rL}]`